# difference between 'base' and 'this' keyword

Tags: c#, .net

I have been told that, a protected variable in the base class can be accessed in the derived class either using `base` or `this` keyword. I am totally confused now, because, `this`  keyword refers to the current class (derived class).

```
public class A
{
  protected int i;
}
public class B :A
{
  void Display()
  {
    this.i=10;
    //  (or)
    base.i=10;
  }
}
```

Is there any technical difference ? First of all, today I am pondered to see why I cannot create an object of A inside `Display()` method and access the variable i through that object as the very definition of protected access says that, it can be accessed in any derived class. Folks, I have seen some threads, however what they say is, we cannot create object and access the protected members. I feel, this is pretty contrary to the definition.

Could someone can please explain me both of my above questions

Comment: *Is there any technical difference ?* No, neither `this.i` nor `base.i` will compile because `i` is defined in `A` and `B` is a different class. Did you mean to say `public class B : A`?

Comment: `this`,`base` in your code won't be able to access `i`..you are not inheriting A

Comment: Assuming you meant to inherit from `A` (but otherwise keep things the same) then there is no difference with the current code. However, if you were to add a field called `i` to class `B`, then `this.i` would refer to that field, whereas `base.i` would still refer to the base class version.

Comment: Your second question is answered here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/why-can-t-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Hey good catch, sorry, typo. Corrected it :) Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between this and base and Best practices of use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733234/difference-between-this-and-base-and-best-practices-of-use)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between 'base' and 'this' when referring to the parent object field, property or method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614559/is-there-any-difference-between-base-and-this-when-referring-to-the-parent-o)

Comment: @dlev: Wow thank you so much, I experimented and got the difference between base and this in this context as you mentioned. But, I also have observed that, just 'i" without this or base keywords refers to B.i. Does that mean this.i =i ?

Comment: @Divine If you do not use either `this` or `base`, then `i` has an *implicit* `this` in front of it (unless there is also a *local variable or parameter* named `i`, which would take precedence.)

Comment: The `i` without a prefix is usually the same as `this.i` except when 'i' is defined in the immediate context (such as an argument to a method) -- dlev beat me to it.

Comment: @dlev: Thank you so much, that perfectly and quickly answered my question in the way I can chew :) I will have a look at your link on protected member access in derived class :) Thanks again!!! :) :)

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple:

`this` refers to the current object (EG, if a method is like `void mymethod(int myvar)`, and the class has `myvar` defined in it, you can use `myvar` to refer to the argument, and `this.myvar` to refer to the the one in the class.)

`base` refers to the base class (The class your class is derived from). (EG, if you're overwriting a method `Update`, at the end of it, you can then call `base.Update();` to call the original method.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's B extend A class, so, B inherite i of A:

```
public class A {
    protected int i;
}
public class B : A {
    void Display() {
        i = 10; // this.i
    }
}
```

Comment: ... You appear to have posted this before you finished writing it.

Comment: How does that gain you more rep? If your answer is not as good as someone elses, I'm not going to +1 someone just because they make a 1st Post.

Comment: @PatrickMagee - the `edit it within 5 minutes` would be editing it to match someone else's answer, but maybe with a little bit of common-sense clarification. And uh... I don't think this guy's doing it, he just forgot to make his post make sense.